# Django redirecting http -> https

Tags: python, django, http, redirect, https

I am running:

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:44100
```

And this is redirecting me to `https`:

```
» http http://localhost:44100/
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 14:09:09 GMT
Location: https://localhost:44100/
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.14
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Why / how is this happening? What setting does control whether `Django` accepts `http` / `https`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `runserver` command only handles http.

However if you have `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` set to `True` then you will be redirected from http to https.

See the Django docs on [SSL/HTTPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/security/#ssl-https) for more information.

Comment: How do I revert it back to the previous setting to test in dev mode?

Comment: @RemoBajwa You can set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False` or remove the line from your settings. Another option might be to move `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` into an if statement like `if not DEBUG:`. Once you've changed the settings, clear your browser cache so that it doesn't continue to redirect.

Comment: Thanks! Since my browser received a permanent redirection (301) I had to clear the page cache in order to get it to work.

Comment: Something else to watch out for, if you are setting from an environment variable in `.env` say, do NOT do `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=os.environ['SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT']` as that is a string not a bool and does not eval to True as you might expect.

Answer (score 36):

My best guess is that in the `settings.py` file of your project you have set

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

which causes your http to redirect to https. You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect).

If that is the case, you might want to remove that line and clear your browser cache before it starts to work as intended.

Comment: This one worked with me, I'm using Heroku as a host for Django application.

Comment: "clear browser cache" saved my life. Thanks @Saransh

Comment: @AshishJohnson: Happy to help since I faced a similar problem if the cache was not cleared.

Comment: @AshishJohnson in fact i think deleting search history do the thing. If anyone needs to preserve cache and cookies