# Letsencrypt certificate renewal issue on Ubuntu 18.04 machine using Apache Server

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, lets-encrypt

I am using Apache servers to host my Django (v2.1) app. I've installed Letsencrypt certificate for HTTPS. Now the time of renewal has come and it is giving me some unauthorized access error.

When I run `sudo certbot` command, I got the following output.

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: noppera.tk
2: www.noppera.tk
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 2
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for www.noppera.tk
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.noppera.tk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.noppera.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/U0D416-6zOf7YRW0jAVIG8oiLthmpy_xmewRdUlwrQM [34.240.58.158]: 400

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.noppera.tk
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.noppera.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/U0D416-6zOf7YRW0jAVIG8oiLthmpy_xmewRdUlwrQM
   [34.240.58.158]: 400

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Also if I run this for option 1, I got the same error. (If you want, I can paste that log too)

**What I've already tried is the following:**

- Has already installed `django-letsencrypt==3.0.1`
- Added `letsencrypt` in `settings.py`
- Added the following line in `urls.py` `url(r'^\.well-known/', include('letsencrypt.urls')),`

Right now site is accessible using HTTPS. Can anyone help me out renewing the certificate?

**EDIT 1**

Option 1 Logs:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: noppera.tk
2: www.noppera.tk
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 1
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for noppera.tk
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. noppera.tk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from https://noppera.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/y6dj0WW9qDgZiBnDTmXmA5FTSusyjabeE3dZs5eEGpI [34.240.58.158]: "\n\n<html>\n<head>\n  <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<style>\n    /*"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: noppera.tk
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://noppera.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/y6dj0WW9qDgZiBnDTmXmA5FTSusyjabeE3dZs5eEGpI
   [34.240.58.158]: "\n\n<html>\n<head>\n  <script
   src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<style>\n
   /*"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

**Django Log for option 1 (noppera.tk)**

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '{{HOST IP}}'. You may need to add '{{HOST IP}}' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /console/login/LoginForm.jsp
Not Found: /.well-known/acme-challenge/WRiDAIe3JPBlZXVWduKBYKrmYKbyS3I2eetsth0YBD0
```

**Django Log for option 2 (www.noppera.tk)**

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.noppera.tk'. You may need to add 'www.noppera.tk' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /.well-known/acme-challenge/GTX3_zQ6XPymDUn1WVZ_27vO_XtYxPClBD5uA8Y1nhM
```

Right now, `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`

**EDIT 2**

Changed `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["www.noppera.tk", "*"]` for Option 2, but same error.

Comment: Is the site additionally accessible via HTTP? The url is above in the message and needs to be accessisible too externally. When I try it from here, I indeed get "Bad Request (400)"

Comment: I don't think so , but I assume it cannot be accessed via http

(to be honest, someone else did first time setup, so I've a minimal idea, sorry for that).

Comment: "Right now site is accessible using HTTPS". FYI I'm also getting a 400 Bad Request for the root of the site over HTTPS from here i.e. for https://www.noppera.tk/

Comment: Oh yes, I can see that but if you open without "www", it works https://noppera.tk, not sure about this ..

Comment: can you access the django logs? If it returns a 400 error then it must be raising an error and logging it.

Comment: I can see (using the working non-www version) via `curl` that http:// is redirecting to https://. I expect this is due to how its configured in Apache. It needs to NOT redirect for the .well-known or temporarily turn off the redirection while you renew the certifiate. How you do that I'm not sure. Potentially check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112365/django-redirecting-http-https

Comment: @ClaireFurney the actual url called by the certbot isn't redirecting, it just returns a 400 bad request. Only logs on the server will be able to tell where the bad request comes from. It could be apache (unlikely), or django (more likely).

Comment: Option 2 from the excerpt returns 400 Bad Request. We don't have the error message for Option 1...

Comment: also, did you migrate after installing django-letsencrypt and did you create the challenges in the admin site?

Comment: added more info. please have a look.

Comment: Hey guys, do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Posting to help others.

The problem was lying with the duplicate conf in the `apache2/sites-available` folder. There were 2 default configs and 2 custom config for my site (for each http and https). So what I did was **disable the default config and reload Apache** using `sudo a2dissite default-ssl.conf` and `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`.

After that I executed `sudo certbot` and it renewed certificates successfully.

Few of the useful resources are below:

1. https://www.jbarrett.me/blog/items/4/setting-ssl-django-app-lets-encrypt-ubuntu-apache-and-mod_wsgi
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-5-%E2%80%94-setting-up-virtual-hosts-(recommended)